# Array element value is not changing when calling delist function

Tags: solidity, javascript, openzeppelin

I am new to Solidity and I am currently making a simple marketplace.
I am using an upgradable contract pattern and my front-end interacts with the proxy contract.
The `_delist` function runs successfully, but does not change the value of the item in the array. If I use a regular smart contract (no proxy) it works. I think I am missing something basic.

I pass in the `array index` from the front-end to the `delist` function (`_NftId`). This function works without the proxy, but now with the proxy it's not working correctly.

```js
    struct NFTListings {
        uint256 id;
        address nftAddress;
        uint256 tokenId;
        uint256 price;
        string  nftName;
        string  nftImage;
        string  nftDescription;
        address listingTokenAddress;
        string listingTokenName;
        string listingTokenSymbol;
        address seller;
        uint256 expiration;
        bool isListed; 
        bool isSold;
    }

    
    /// @notice Array of listings
    NFTListings[]  private  listings;
    
       /// @notice Acts like constructor() for upgradeable contracts
    function initialize( )
        external
        initializer
    {
        __Ownable_init();
        __ReentrancyGuard_init();
    }
    

    
    function _createListing(
    address _nftAddress,
    uint256 _tokenId,
    string memory _nftName,
    string memory _image,
    string memory _description,
    address _listingTokenAddress, 
    string memory _listingTokenName, 
    string memory _listingTokenSymbol,
    uint256 price,
    uint256 expiration
) internal {
    require(_nftAddress != address(0), "zero address");
    require(price > 0, "zero amount");

     uint256 _id = listings.length;
    NFTListings memory _NftListing = NFTListings(
        _id, 
        _nftAddress,
        _tokenId,
        price,
        _nftName,
        _image,
        _description,
        _listingTokenAddress,
        _listingTokenName,
        _listingTokenSymbol,
        msg.sender,
        expiration,
        true,
        false
    );
    listings.push(_NftListing);
   }
    function delist(
        uint256 _NftId, // Array index passed in from frontend 
         address _nftAddress,
        uint256 _tokenId,
        string memory _nftName,
        string memory _image,
        string memory _description
        ) external {
        
        listings[_NftId].isListed = false; // Uses array index passed from frontend
        emit Delisted(_NftId, _nftAddress, _tokenId, _nftName, _image,            _description);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

(UPDATE) The solution had nothing to do with the smart contract. The index I was passing from the front-end was not matching the array index in the smart contract. Changed the front-end call to   `const nftIndex = new BigNumber(activeListings[index].id);` and sent nftIndex to the smart contract.